# Is there a way to check the Avalara API Status in a programmatic way?

Tags: avalara

Sometimes, Avalara services might be be down due to some internal issue. We check the status by visiting  https://status.avalara.com/

We are building some function in the back end which needs to be triggered only when Avalara Service is down. 
Is there any API which checks, is Avalara is Up and running?

PS : I went through, **Ping** API but not confident on it. Is there a way I could test it?

https://developer.avalara.com/api-reference/avatax/rest/v2/methods/Utilities/Ping/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avalara Ping API returns

> PingResultModel

.
So in case, if there are issues with the Avalara API - all the properties of PingResultModel will be null.

So on checking the

> version

property of PingResultModel, we can find whether Avalara Service is up or not.

> PingResultModel :
>   https://developer.avalara.com/api-reference/avatax/rest/v2/models/PingResultModel/

Answer (score 0):

Use  GET  https://sandbox-rest.avatax.com/api/v2/utilities/ping  using your Account Username and Password.

cURL:

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'https://sandbox-rest.avatax.com/api/v2/utilities/ping' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic bXl1c2VyaWQ6bXlwYXNzd29yZA=='
```

**Example Response:**

```json
{
    "version": "21.7.0",
    "authenticated": true,
    "authenticationType": "UsernamePassword",
    "authenticatedUserName": "my.username",
    "authenticatedUserId": 123456,
    "authenticatedAccountId": 1100001234,
    "authenticatedCompanyId": 0
}
```